# Set (and remove) keyword arguments from function

Tags: python, function

I have a function like:
`def foo(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c`

Now I like to fix b to 2 and create signature:
`def bar(a, c):
    return foo(a, 2, c)`

Another option is to use a lambda function:
`bar = lambda a, *args: foo(a,2,*args)`

But also this is not very nice, because I have to know how many arguments there are before b.

`functools.partial` solves this problem partially:
`bar = partial(foo, b=2)`

However, this has a signature `bar(a, b=2, c)` instead of bar(a, c)

Is there a better solution?

**Background:** Currently, I try to fit data using scipy.optimize.minimize. Some parameters I want to fix (not changing during fitting).

Comment: before answer let me note that, `bar(a, b=2, c)` will raise `SyntaxError` saying  `non-default argument follows default argument`

Answer (score 1):

consider nested functions, if matches your need. 
a great [blog post](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) about nested/decorator functions

```
>>> def outer(a, c):
...     def inner(b=2):
...             return a+b+c
...     return inner
... 
>>> dec = outer(3,5)
>>> print dec()
10
```